# Command inside if statement of bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, syntax-error

I have the following line as part of a much bigger bash script:

```
if [ `packages/TinySVM-0.09/bin/svm_learn 2>&1| grep TinySVM | wc -l | cut -c0-7 | sed 's/^  *//g'` -eq 1 ]
```

upon running the script, I get:

> ./install.sh: line 219: [: -eq: unary operator expected

Where line 219 is the line above. Any suggestions for a fix?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This happens when you are using the `test` builtin via `[` and your left side expression returns NUL.  You can fix this by the use of:

```
if [ x`some | expression | here` = x1 ]; then
```

Or, since you're already using bash you can use its much nicer `(( ))` syntax which doesn't have this problem and do:

```
if (( $(some | expression | here) == 1 )); then
```

Note that I also used `$()` for command substitution over backticks `` as the latter is non-POSIX and deprecated

Answer (score 47):

You can run your command without any additional syntax. For example, the following checks the exit code of grep to determine whether the regular expression matches or not:

```
if ! grep -q "$word" /usr/share/dict/words
then
    echo "Word $word is not valid word!"
fi
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use this technique, because it is mentioned pretty seldomly?

Comment: Probably I found the reason myself: With grep that works well, but with other commands, that might output sth. (and not just return a code), this output will be printed to stdout. What is about ````if command >& /dev/null; then ...````?

Comment: If the command ouput something it is indeed better to use `if ! cmp foo.txt bar.txt > /dev/null 2> /dev/null ;then ...`

Answer (score 8):

The error occurs because your command substitution returns nothing effectively making your test look like:

```
if [ -eq 1 ]
```

A common way to fix this is to append some constant on both sides of the equation, so that no operand becomes empty at any time:

```
if [ x`packages/TinySVM-0.09/bin/svm_learn 2>&1| grep TinySVM | wc -l | cut -c0-7 | sed 's/^  *//g'` = x1 ]
```

Note that `=` is being used as we are now comparing strings.

Answer (score 6):

Try [[ test_expression ]]; instead of [ test_expression ];

Answer (score 6):

You could add an "x" to both sides of the comparison or you could just quote the left side:

```
[ "$(command | pipeline)" = 1 ]
```

I don't understand what the `cut` and `sed` at the end are for. The output of `wc -l` in a pipeline is simply a number.